# Finding PFUsers from Parse - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, database, database-design, parse-platform

My iPhone application has to search for same phone numbers stored up on Parse. The flow is,

- 1) Get contacts from user phone.
- 2) See if each of those number exist on parse for other PFUser.
- 3) Show Results by fetching PFUser with    that number.

  This is same as whatsapp where we can see our contacts Using Whatsapp. So basically I know to make query and find out the users but my question is, is this Optimised way? For example if I have 50 contacts and each number will be obviously compared till match is found and if there are 1k/10K/More.. users then it will be very intensive work! So please help me find out great and fastest way for it, as I am beginner in using parse, any help appreciated. Thanks a lot experts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [Parse docs for PFQuery](http://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html)?

Assuming each PFUser has an attribute like `phoneNumber`, something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumber in %@", phoneNumbersArray];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[PFUser parseClassName] predicate:predicate];
NSArray *pfUsers = [query findObjects];
```

There shouldn't be much more too it, unless you've changed something else, such as making PFUser rows not readable by others via ACL.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I know to query such, the question is optimisation!! Like I have mentioned in my question that if I have 50 contacts and for example total users are 1000/10,000 or 100,000 etc then the query will search each contact through all users and Consider Worst case i.e user found at the end of the Table, then it would be really time consuming. How it will be optimised under that situation! Like I have to use some sorting, paging algorithms etc! Or could you please tell some statistic that parse queries are optimised or will handle by own!

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Just use the `limit` and `skip` properties on the PFQuery instance to enact pagination.

Comment: I should also note, in case it's not clear: that's *one* query above ... it just may return a lot of users. So if it the large return set you are concerned about, try `limit` and `skip` to do pagination of results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear if you are worried about the speed of the query or the size of the resultset, but I believe it is the query.

It is not like each of your phone numbers will be compared with every entry in your parse.com table. Parse makes handling your backend easy for you, by optimizing how queries are performed against your classes.

You can use a straightforward query constraint for your search. Put all the phone numbers you want to query for in an array, and then create a query like this:

```
PFQuery query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"phone" containedIn: arrayWithPhoneNumbers];
```

This will return a result set including all users with a phone number that matches any of the numbers in arrayWithPhoneNumbers.